# Get a list of opened Word files in Python

Tags: python, win32com

I need to get all opened Word files and find one, that has a special string in its content.

We have 3 word documents opened: Test.docx, Test2.doc and blabla.doc

EDITED: let's concentrate only on finding all opened docs.

```
word = win32com.client.GetObject(None, 'Word.Application')
for doc in word.Documents:
    print("Next document is " + doc.name)
```

As a result it finds only one file, that was opened the last. And does not get the others. Output:

```
> Next document is blabla.doc

> Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, what to do, to get all opened files?

Comment: Maybe specify the file location when you call it?

Comment: You have a typo: `word.Docuuments` ... are you sure you're posting the code you're actually running?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Corrected a typo, but it was only here. I had to retype a code. In Pycharm there was "Documents".

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on windows10 system. It lists all files opened by winword.exe. Not only the documents, therefore the result must be filtered for real documents:*.doc,*.docx.

```
l = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'winword.exe'.upper() in p.info['name']]

if len(l) > 0:
  pid =l[0]['pid']
else:
  # No winword.exe found
  return []

p = psutil.Process(pid)
fileList = p.as_dict(attrs=['open_files']) # Get the list of all files opened by winword.exe. It must be filtered on doc, docx because there are many other files.
```